# Horizontal AJAX posts loader, detect when scrollbar reaches the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll, infinite-scroll

I've set up a div (#reviewspostscont) with overflow-x:scroll, now i want to load posts with AJAX but I cant't detect when the scrollbar gets to the very right end.
Down below is the code I have so far, I can't understand whats wrong with it.
Thanks in advance,
Matt

```
   $('#reviewspostscont').scroll(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   scrollPercentage = 100 * $(this).scrollLeft() / ($('#reviewspostscont').width() - $(this).width());

                if  (scrollPercentage == 100){
                    alert('end!');  // just to test the code, then AJAX
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is around how you calculate the total scroll width. I have added a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neelsg/yh4myz4h/)**. Basically, instead of:

```
scrollPercentage = 100 * $(this).scrollLeft() / 
    ($('#reviewspostscont').width() - $(this).width());
```

You should have:

```
scrollPercentage = 100 * $(this).scrollLeft() /
    ($(this)[0].scrollWidth - $(this).width());
```

Comment: I forgot it there when I changed the code, worked perfectly thanks!